# Eclipse Not by-passing the Network Settings

Tags: eclipse, networking, proxy

I have to fetch the Updates
I tried using Manual Settings under Window ==> Preferences ==> Network Settings ==> Manual.
 I tried removing the Authenticaton which is blurred in the image below 
  am using the same procedure with other softwares like Orbit Downloader,... Only Eclipse is not working Now what am i supposed to do now?
 Please suggest a Solution,
 **Configurations**
 Windows-7 
 Eclipse - Indigo
 [image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things - either change from 'Manual' to 'Direct' and bypass the proxy completely, or if your system has centrally configured proxy (a software like Access Connections can do this), then change to 'Native', and let Eclipse pick up the system settings.

Comment: Tried all the settings, Nothing is working, Need help, its urgent